# Multiple div elements swapped out based on where the user clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dynamic

I have a website I'm trying to dynamicize. I've decided to have each page with the tags

```
  <div id=divID' style='display:none' onmouseclick='appear()' > ... </div>
```

JS will change the style.display of the specific element to inline, but make the other elements style.display="none".

```
appear(){
  document.getElementByID('divID).style.display='inline';
  ...
}
```

I have little experience with jquery, but I'm willing to learn if I need to,

I'm unsure if I'm phrasing this right, so if you need more information I'd be happy to help :)

Chris

**EDIT**

The user has a taskbar, completely visible. When they click on a button in the taskbar, I want the page's div element to change from none to inline. When the user clicks another of the buttons, I want the button they were previously viewing to change back to display:none and have the new div to display.

**EDIT DOS**

```
<div id="taskbar" onclick="showDiv()" >

        <a id="about" href="/about" >
            ABOUT</a>

        <a id="speakers" href="/speakers">
            SPEAKERS
        </a>
        <a id="team"  href="/team">
            TEAM
        </a>
        <a id="tickets" href="/tickets" >
            TICKETS
        </a>
        <a id="sponsors" href="/sponsors" >
            SPONSORS
        </a>
        <a id="contact-us" href="/contact">
            CONTACT US
        </a>
        <a id="home-page" href='/' class="button">
            HOME
        </a>
</div>
```

As for the JS code, I'm liking Jeff Clarke's idea. I will try it out and let you know if it works!

Comment: How is the user going to click on an element that isn't displayed?

Comment: I've edited the question above to better reflect my situation. Please, read through the **EDIT** & let me know if you're better able to answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the something to `display:none` it is essentially invisible to interaction -- it won't respond to click events.

**UPDATE**

Add click events to your buttons to show and hide the various DIVs.

```
<button onclick="showDIV('divID1')">Show 1</button>
<button onclick="showDIV('divID2')">Show 2</button>
```

And in your javascript:

```
var curDiv;

function showDiv(id) {
  //hide current div
  if (curDiv != null) {
    document.getElementByID(curDiv).style.display="none";
  } 
  document.getElementByID(id).style.display="inline";
  curDiv = id;
}
```

Comment: I edited my question. The user interacting with the page is presented with a taskbar. When the user clicks one of the buttons on the taskbar, the corresponding page changes from display:none to display:inline. Does this make more sense? 

I apologize for having asked such a vague question. The problem is that it's not even fully coded yet on my end & have little to go off of when phrasing my question.

Comment: OK.  You need to add click handlers to your buttons, not the DIVs that you want to show and hide.

Comment: Noted. But won't the DOM chain make all of the elements nested underneath the div element appear as well?

I wrote up some code that I'll add to the question in a second, so you can have a a better idea of what we're (trying) to deal with.

Comment: Yeah I think I need to see the example.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it. Firstly it will have a particular proportion visible to user and clicking on it... it will show complete details and others will be squeezed. If I am correct... then this is actually called accordion. And here is the solution:

What we will do actually... We will fix its height or  width and put overflow:hidden to hide extra content outside. This we will do in its CSS.

Now onClick we will add a class lets say.. 'current'

In its definition we will increase div's height/width to an extent like 400px or something as per our requirement. * We can use css transition to make smooth effect with: transition: all .5s ease-in-out;

Now we will first remove '.current' class from all the div elements in that group and then add it on the clicked one using 'this'....

Look below for jQuery...

```
$('#idOfParentContainer .classCommonOnDivs').on('click', function(){
        $('#idOfParentContainer .classCommonOnDivs').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');
    });
```

And if you need 'Tab Structure', which you mentioned recently in your question edit, then you may use the following code...
It says by clicking on button 'x' with title 'fDiv' open div which have id='fDiv', clicking on button 'y' with title 'sDiv' open div which have id='sDiv' and clicking on button 'z' with title 'tDiv' open div which have id='tDiv'.

So HTML structure...

```
<div id="parent">
    <button id="x" title="fDiv">Clicked for First Div</button>
    <button id="y" title="sDiv">Clicked for First Div</button>
    <button id="z" title="tDiv">Clicked for First Div</button>
</div>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="fDiv">First Div Content</div>
    <div id="sDiv">Second Div Content</div>
    <div id="tDiv">Third Div Content</div>
</div>
```

Now the jQuery:

```
$('#parent button').on('click', function(){
    $('#parent button').removeClass('current'); /*For remove formatting of 'current button' */
    $(this).addClass('current'); /*For formatting '.current button differently' */
    $('.tab-content > div').hide(); /*First of all hiding all divs*/
    $('.tab-content > div').removeClass('current');/*Removing '.current' class if uses*/
    var tabId=$(this).attr('title');/*Taking value of ID from clicked button's title.*/
    $('#'+tabId+'').fadeIn(400); /* Display:block the current div*/
    $('#'+tabId+'').addClass('current');/* Adding class if need any specific formatting, not necessary to do this*/
});
```